# "Мерить" или "мерять"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "мерить" или "мерять", если речь идет:

об измерении чего-либо;

о примерке чего-либо?

Comment: измерЯть (что делать?)

измЕрить (что сделать?)

Comment: примерять (что делать?)

примерить (что сделать?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В обоих случаях мерить (мерю, меришь, мерят) - нормативно, мерять (меряю, меряешь, меряют) - разговорный вариант.

Вообще не надо грамматически разделять эти случаи, это одно слово с немного разделившимися значениями.

Answer (score 4):

"Получив от этого некоторое облегчение, он отходил и вновь начинал мерить взад и вперёд пыльную дорогу, ведущую на вершину" (М. Булгаков).
"Приезжал раз техник, мерил болото и дал Жмыху план" (А. Платонов).

Интересно, писатели сами выбрали форму "мерить" или их комп. заставил переделать? И откуда вообще взялось слово "мерять"?  В др.-рус. (с 11 века) языке существовал глагол ***мѣрити.***
Кажется, что суффикс Я — это просторечный вариант суффикса И по аналогии с видовыми парами: бросать - бросить, выполнять — выполнить, решать — решить, возвращать — возвратить, встречать — встретить, объявлять — объявить.

Answer (score 1):

Когда речь идет об измерении чего-либо, употребляйте "мерить", как Вам уже посоветовал behemothus, когда говорится о примерке, - "примерять".

Comment: Мерять - форма разговорная, лучше ее никогда не использовать на письме. Но вот У Даля: Чужого на свой аршин не меряй. С пословицами как быть?

Comment: Мне кажется (ну, это мое личное мнение, притом не слишком авторитетное), лучше сохранить оригинальную орфографию. Ведь такие пословицы, как "Неча на зеркало пенять, коли рожа крива" мы не приводим в соответствие с современными нормами русского литературного языка.

Comment: Забавное противостояние : писатели вовсю употребляют народные разговорные слова, а народ заставляют говорить и писать исключительно правильными и стерильными  словоформами)  
>**Дмитрий Быков. Орфография** (2002)  
Внизу по диагонали мерял комнату Зуев ― не мог заснуть: видимо, от переживаний этого дня.  
[Как меряют писатели](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%E5%F0%FF%EB)

Comment: Варианты «мерил» и «мерял» читаются одинаково – мер(и)л – совершенно непонятно, зачем тогда писать «мерял». Или они «я» произносят?  Другое дело – личные формы, они и на слух  разные: мерит и меряет. Поэтому «мерял» мне совсем не симпатично, не понимаю я писателей.

Comment: Есть писатели (например, Лев Толстой), а есть писаки.