# Мерялись или мерились?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать "мерЯлись" или "мерИлись" в тексте: "Мер(?)лись две девки коромыслами..."?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Мерить" или "мерять"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 5):

Оба варианта верны.

Мериться - нейтральное литературное. Меряться - разговорное.

Это фрагмент текста разговорного стиля, т. к. употреблено просторечие "девки", следовательно, мерЯлись подойдёт даже больше по стилю, чем нормативное мерИлись.

Answer (score 2):

"Мы были дети двора. Мер**я**лись силой. Стыкались до первой кровянки".

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: Матвей, спасибо. Я это уже тоже просмотрела. Просмотрите, пожалуйста,здесь :https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/мериться

Comment: Кстати, Ирина, это ответ не Матвея, он только отредактировал его.

Answer (score 1):

В словарях:  мерить (нейтр.) и мерять (разг.). Поэтому в тексте, если это не передача разговора, правильно: мерить.

Comment: _**Серж**: ...правильно: мерить._ === Да бросьте Вы! По-моему, в сочетании с _**девками**_ и _**коромыслами**_ требовать употребления _**нейтр.**_ глагола _**мерить**_ просто смешно!

Comment: Слава, так я и не спорю. Здесь разговорная лексика. Поэтому я написал: если это ***НЕ*** разговорная лексика, правильно мер***и***ть.