# Допустима ли форма "померЯть"?

Tags: орфография

В современном русском языке принято писать "помер**и**ть", вариант "помер**я**ть" считается диалектным. А допустимо ли использование формы "померять" в литературном тексте первой половины XX века?

Comment: То, что считаете диалектным, здесь общепринято:  http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @shampar Да, спасибо. И здесь уже есть обсуждение https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/Мерить-или-мерять (первый раз почему-то не нашел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В толковом словаре [Д. Н. Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/957242) (1935-1940) отмечено:
ПОМЕ́РИТЬ, померю, померишь, и (***разг***.) **померяю, померяешь**, совер.
**1.** что. То же, что примерить в 1 знач. и смерить. Померить новое пальто.
**2.** без доп. и что. Провести некоторое время, меряя что-нибудь. (Встречается также написание **померять, померял**.)

*Старик **померял** уровень нефти в резервуаре, слез и осветил грязный клочок бумаги, исписанный цифрами* (К. Г. Паустовский. Ночь в Доссоре [1930]).

*— Ты у нас, Мануйло, похож на медведя: первое, тем похож, что никому нельзя, а ему можно, и только за то, что медведь. Второе, тем похож, что когда он встает и выходит весной из берлоги, то подымется на задние лапы, **померяется** на первой елочке и делает загрыз. Так и ты встал и меряешься со всем колхозом* (М. М. Пришвин. Корабельная чаща [1946-1950]).

Современные словари (например, [МАС](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-58006.htm)) также относят форму *померять* к разговорной.