# Он мерит или меряет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Давно назрел вопрос об этом. Только что в очередной раз [обсуждались](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457694/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C) варианты окончаний этого глагола. И всё же меня интересует иной аспект.

Все мы знаем, что *"мер**и**ть" — строгий нормативный* вариант, которому культурный человек в большинстве случаев следует, а *"мер**я**ть" — разговорный* вариант.

И действительно, если заглянуть в Национальный корпус, находишь **[29](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB)** вхождений на *"он мер**и**л"* и всего **[два](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BB)** на *"он мер**я**л".*
Зато в настоящем времени 1-го и 3-го лица картина принципиально меняется! Находится по **девять** вхождений на *"[я мер**яю**](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E)"* и *"[он мер**яе**т](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82)"* против **трёх** на оба *"[я мер**ю**](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8E)"* и *"[он мер**и**т](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82)".* По формам множественного числа примерно такая же статистика, то есть преобладание *разговорного* варианта примерно **в три раза**. *Странно* лишь то, что на *"ты мер**яе**шь"* я вообще **ничего** не нашёл, а на *"ты мер**и**шь"* есть **два** вхождения.

*Почему так меняется статистика в зависимости от формы слова? И как лучше говорить в быту в настоящем времени: как большинство, то есть выбирать разговорный вариант, или выбирать классический и странно выделяться при этом из общей массы? Надо ли говорить иначе в других жизненных ситуациях (докладчику, лектору, диктору, актёру на сцене, работнику солидной компании и пр.)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на Ваш, Артём, вопрос даёт главный редактор портала «Грамота.ру», член экспертного совета Тотального диктанта Владимир Пахомов.  Он отмечает, что Академический «Русский орфографический словарь» под редакцией В.В. Лопатина и О.Е. Ивановой - самый полный орфографический словарь современного русского языка - дает однозначное указание: «мерить(ся)», «мерил(ся)», «мерила(сь)». Вариант «мерялся», «мерялась», «мерялись» не указывается в качестве допустимого ни в этом, ни в других нормативных орфографических словарях.
**Предпочтительно (в строгой литературной речи)**: *мерить, мерю, меришь, мерит*; **допустимо: *меряю, меряешь, меряет*** (эти формы отличаются по звучанию от форм глагола «мерить»). А вот в прошедшем времени - только «мерил»; вариант «мерял» не допускается (**так как по звучанию он почти не отличается от «мерил»**).

Он подробно разбирает эти варианты употребления форм слова: https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/60076-kak-pravilno-oni-merilis-ili-meryalis-silami/

Так что в быту грамотный человек может вполне сказать *меряю, меряешь, меряет*, а вот докладчику, лектору, диктору, актёру на сцене, работнику солидной компании и пр. лучше говорить  *мерить, мерю, меришь, мерит*.

Но я бы всё-таки на их месте выбрала синоним измерить, измерю, измеришь, измерит.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила!